# JavaScript Objects and public variables

Tags: javascript

I've trying to create a javascript object with public methods and public variables:

```
jeeni.DataGrid = (function(elementId){
    var divId = elementId;
    var div;
    var saveUrl;
    var columns;
    var dataUrl;

    var validate = function(){
        console.log("divId: " + (divId));
        console.log("div: " + div);
        console.log("saveUrl: " + saveUrl);
        console.log("columns: " + columns);
        console.log("dataUrl: " + dataUrl);
    };

    return {
        toString:validate,
        dateURL:dataUrl,
        saveURL:saveUrl,
        columnDefs:columns
    };

});
```

and I use it like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var grid = new jeeni.DataGrid("myDataGrid");

        grid.saveURL = "http://www.jeeni.co.uk/grid/save";
        grid.dataURL = "http://www.jeeni.co.uk/grid/data";
        grid.columnDefs = "[{text:'Column1',width:75}, {text:'Column2',width:150}]";
        grid.toString();
    });
</script>
```

But at the console I get:

```
divId: myDataGrid
div: undefined
saveUrl: undefined
columns: undefined
dataUrl: undefined
```

Can anyone explain why the undefined variables are undefined. Doesn't the return make them public? And how do I get them to be assignable without having to use getters and setters.

Thanks

Comment: _"Doesn't the return make them public?"_ No. It returns the current value of those variables (all of which are undefined), it doesn't return a reference to those variables. You have to use getters and setters, or properties instead of variables (i.e., `this.saveUrl` instead of `var saveUrl`). The `toString:validate` part is different because `validate` is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently taking the private variables, extracting the VALUES, and returning those in an object. The object you're returning has no REFERENCE to the private variables, it merely has a copy. When you reassign a value after calling your function, you're only changing the copy, not the private variable.

What you need to do is store your data directly on an object as all properties on an object are retrieved via REFERENCE. Example:

```
jeeni.DataGrid = function(elementId){

    // These are private
    var divId = elementId;
    var div;

    var public = {
      "toString"   : validate,
      "dateURL"    : null,
      "saveURL"    : null,
      "columnDefs" : null
    };

    function validate(){
        console.log("divId: "   + divId);
        console.log("div: "     + div);
        console.log("saveUrl: " + public.saveURL);
        console.log("columns: " + public.columnDefs);
        console.log("dataUrl: " + public.dataURL);
    };

    return public;

};
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern builds private fields (it's often the main reason it's used). So when you do

```
grid.saveURL = ...
```

you're just adding a new field, not changing the existing hidden one.

If you want public fields, do this :

```
jeeni.DataGrid = function(elementId){
    this.divId = elementId;
};
jeeni.DataGrid.prototype.validate = function(){
    console.log("divId: " + (this.divId));
    console.log("div: " + this.div);
    console.log("saveUrl: " + this.saveUrl);
    console.log("columns: " + this.columns);
    console.log("dataUrl: " + this.dataUrl);
};
```

If you want to keep your fields private, then you must add functions to change them but that would be heavier in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `()` at the end of your function declaration if you want to immediately invoke the function and assign the returned object to `jeeni.DataGrid`. For example,

```
var obj = (function (someArg1) {
    return { pubVar1 : someArg1 };
}("Hello World"));

//Alerts "Hello World".
alert(obj.pubVar1);
```

To test out the return value of your function/variable, you can always use `console.log(obj)` and inspect the output on the browser's debug console (if you are using Chrome F12 usually will display this console).

Hope this helps!